# How to visible tool tip in highcharts while page load

Tags: jquery, highcharts

In my application i want to show all tooltip in visible state while that has been load. And i here submit my code. But in default it's displayed only in mouse over.. Help me for how to do this..

```
$(function () {
     chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
     chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
      },
Axis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Mar', 'May', 'Jul', 'Sep', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    lineWidth: 0,
    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
    lineColor: 'transparent',
    labels: { enabled: false },
    minorTickLength: 0,
    tickLength: 0
    },
yAxis: {
    plotLines: [{
    value: 0,
    width: 1,
    color: '#808080'
            }],
    lineWidth: 0,
    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
    lineColor: 'transparent',
    labels: { enabled: false },
    gridLineColor: 'transparent',
    minorTickLength: 0,
    tickLength: 0
    },
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr>' +
                '<td style="padding:0;"><b>{point.y:.1f} </b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
    },
series: [{
     name: 'Tokyo',
     data: [7.0, 14.5, 21.5, 26.5, 18.3, 9.6]
        }],
  }); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unforunately you cannot display all tooltips (I mean each per  point) becuase we use single tooltip container which is fullfill with correct content on mouseover. Only what you can do is adding divs for each points with defined position (top/left margins) and position absolute.